# How to stop While Loop in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an array that  are having some different values.  one array  called saveforRR this should work like whenever i have any value that less that 0, it will be removed from the array. Also, the values in the array  must reduced by 1. I do not know how many iterations are going to  take to  make my  array Length =0. so I used while loop. However, when i run the code my loop  stops in this line  **fortheaddingvalue = (int)saveforRR[w]; //It says her that  my array is out from boundaries, which i do not know how?**  How can I fix this problem? can you  advise me please?

```
//Create variables and set up the arrays 

int value = 7;
int []  saveforRR = {1,2,3,4,5,15,86};

//start get the values reduced 
int fortheaddingvalue;
int w = 0;

//Run the while loop to  reduce the value in the saveforRR array.                   
while(saveforRRName.Length !=0 && saveforRR.Length !=0)
{                   
    fortheaddingvalue = (int)saveforRR[w]; //It says her that  my array is out from boundaries, which i do not know how? 
    fortheaddingvalue = fortheaddingvalue - 1;

    if (fortheaddingvalue > 0)
    {                        
       saveforRR[w] = fortheaddingvalue;
       txtOutput.Text += "\r\n" +saveforRR[w] + "  this is the value";                     
    }
    else
    {
       Array.Clear(saveforRR, w, 1);           
       txtOutput.Text += "\r\n" + saveforRR[w] + "this is the value Remover";             
    }
    w++;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code using the debugger to see what it's actually doing?

Comment: yes i did several times. but i could not figure where is the error.

Comment: Well, then, update your question with what you found during your investigation. If you step through the code line by line and check the relevant values it should become clear what's wrong pretty quickly.

Comment: Thanks i will  check my code

Comment: I think it would be easier to implement your algorithm if you would use List<int>.

Comment: Thanks i am going to do it now. I hope it will work.

Comment: I got another problem

Comment: That  when I am using the lest it shows to me that i am out of array  rang????????????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The length of your array will never be zero. The `Clear` method doesn't remove items from the array.

An array can't be resized. You can use the `Resize` method to get the same effect, as that will create a new array with a different size, and copy the items to it. That's however not efficient, you should use a `List<int>` instead, as that supports actual resizing.

Comment: Thank you  i am going to  try  the List now

Answer (score 0):

It seems that nobody mentioned the **`break`**-statement. You can use it break out of any loop:

```
while(true)
{
   // Eternal loop here...

   // Break out
   break;
}
```

Read more about it here: [break](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adbctzc4.aspx)

Other ways to exit loop include for example [goto](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/13940fs2.aspx), return or setting the loop expression not to match